# Lost clipboard notifications after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: clipboard, clipboard-manager

Hello I had some clipboard manager installed that always showed content of what I was copying as pop up notification in lower right corner. After upgrade to 22.04 I lost that extremely useful notification.

Can someone advise how to turn on copy notifications, or what is the clipboard manager that has such notificatons?

Comment: Install that "some clipboard manager" again if it is available for Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: My question was which clipboard manager has notifications. I did not remember which was it. It was actually CopyQ that got updated, but with new desktop it did not show the notifications. I had to go to preferences and uncheck "Use native notifications".

Comment: Edit your question, and add the information about which clipboard manager you are talking.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences and uncheck "Use native notifications".